# Make emacs speller work with accented/modified letters

Tags: editors, spelling, characters

In continuation to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex) question I was wondering, now that my document is full of `\'` and other accents, the emacs speller balks on all the words... Is there a way to get a spell-checker to understand `\'e` as é and thus spell-check the document properly?

Comment: This is really a question about ispell (or similar) and emacs, rather than TeX or friends. It is, however, relevant enough to people interested in TeX that I guess it's acceptable...

Comment: I was thinking that emacs is a friend...but vote to close if you fine it outside our scope...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** I realize that I have completely misguided this answer. My answer is basically a recommendation to type normally without escaping accents, which is easier and might be better for the spell-checker.

---

I had previously some problems with emacs and these type of characters. It was specially annoying to write them like that in the first place. So my tips are:

- use utf8 inputenc, like the question that you referred: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- make sure that your file is in utf-8. In emacs `M-x` -> `set-buffer-file-coding-system` -> `utf-8` Or simply `C-x RET f` -> `utf-8`
- Type characters normally, like Información, grève, coïncidence. In emacs I use `M-x` `set-input-method` -> `latin-1-prefix`. Your choice depends on your language or preference.
- To convert your already typed document, select an area (or the whole document) and use `M-x` `iso-tex2iso`. Chech the other versions of `iso-*` functions that may help you as well to transform back and forward to several formats.

Example of `iso-*` functions:

```
Original (how I type it):
Información, grève, coïncidence.

iso-iso2tex of the phrase above:
Informaci{\'o}n, gr{\`e}ve, co{\"\i}ncidence.

Your format:
Informaci\'on, gr\`eve, co\"incidence

iso-tex2iso of the phrase above:
Información, grève, coïncidence.
```

Comment: I found this page useful for those of us that don't typically type with accents and diacritical marks: https://masteringemacs.org/article/diacritics-in-emacs