# How to convert characters to LaTeX code?

Tags: conversion, characters

How to convert characters of type `á ê õ ção` to `\'a \^e \~o \c{c} \~a` automatically?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you save your source file as UTF-8, and use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you can keep them in your source.

Comment: Also, the answer likely depends on how you'd like to do it. In your editor? In LaTeX? In a preprocessing step?

Comment: Alan Munn, i use [utf8]{inputenc}, but is possible convert directly in edit file.tex?

Comment: if you use an editor that has automatic spellchecking rules, you can probably define new rules that would do that.  The same way i is often automatically changed to I.  But a detailed answer is highly dependent on the editor you're using.

Comment: an example of any one editor please.

Comment: These links might be useful: [Python - Replace all accented characters by their LaTeX equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578912/replace-all-accented-characters-by-their-latex-equivalent) and [UTF-8 support via inputenc](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/utf8ienc.pdf).

Comment: I'm tempted to reply to your comment with a solution using TeXShop for the Mac, but that might be obnoxious... If you want to do this in your editor, you really need to tell us which one.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @Alan and @You's first comments and add that you haven't described the extent of the replacement. Are you only referring to the characters in your post, or a more general setting of 'all accented' characters? Also are these accented characters contained in a single .tex file, or possibly dispersed among several that you use via `\include{...}`, `\includeonly{...}` and/or `\input{...}`? If all of the latter hold, then the stream editor `sed` would work. Otherwise a simple find-and-replace would suffice.

Comment: Reverse direction: [unicode - Convert LaTex accented characters to UTF8 equivalent with Python - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447766/convert-latex-accented-characters-to-utf8-equivalent-with-python)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick python script that does the trick, it handles both combining accents as well as pre-composed characters, however it takes only a string of text and some extra work is needed to handle complete TeX files:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unicodedata
import sys

accents = {
    0x0300: '`', 0x0301: "'", 0x0302: '^', 0x0308: '"',
    0x030B: 'H', 0x0303: '~', 0x0327: 'c', 0x0328: 'k',
    0x0304: '=', 0x0331: 'b', 0x0307: '.', 0x0323: 'd',
    0x030A: 'r', 0x0306: 'u', 0x030C: 'v',
}

def uni2tex(text):
    out = ""
    txt = tuple(text)
    i = 0
    while i < len(txt):
        char = text[i]
        code = ord(char)

        # combining marks
        if unicodedata.category(char) in ("Mn", "Mc") and code in accents:
            out += "\\%s{%s}" %(accents[code], txt[i+1])
            i += 1
        # precomposed characters
        elif unicodedata.decomposition(char):
            base, acc = unicodedata.decomposition(char).split()
            acc = int(acc, 16)
            base = int(base, 16)
            if acc in accents:
                out += "\\%s{%s}" %(accents[acc], unichr(base))
            else:
                out += char
        else:
            out += char

        i += 1

    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = unicode(sys.argv[1], "utf-8")
    print(uni2tex(t))
```

and invoked as:

```
$ python uni2tex.py "á ê õ ção ̆ a ă ̆a"
```

which outputs `\'{a} \^{e} \~{o} \c{c}\~{a}o \u{ }a \u{a} \u{a}`.

Comment: Characters like æ ø Æ Ø ð Ð are not translated by the script.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen: You can always extend it, I don’t know the LaTeX csnames for these myself.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to keep a version of your document with the unreplaced characters as it is much easier to read. If you use makefiles to process your documents, you might write something along these lines

```
#! -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

SHELL = /bin/sh
DOCUMENT = doc

$(DOCUMENT).pdf : $(DOCUMENT).tex
    cp $(DOCUMENT).tex temp_$(DOCUMENT).tex
    sed -i "s/é/\\\'{e}/g" temp_$(DOCUMENT).tex
    sed -i 's/ç/\\c{c}/g' temp_$(DOCUMENT).tex
    # more substitutions to add...
    pdflatex temp_$(DOCUMENT).tex
    cp temp_$(DOCUMENT).pdf $(DOCUMENT).pdf
```

Actually all my makefiles copy *doc.tex* to *temp_doc.tex* before doing anything. This way, I can easily clean up any machine generated files via `rm -f temp*`.

However, are you really sure you want to do this? Replacing these characters with their respective macros doesn't really give you any advantage. (At least none I could readily see.) But it comes at the cost of poor kerning. (See also section 2.2.6
of [l2tabuen](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/).)

Best

Answer (score 3):

If you use emacs, use the `iso-` functions. In your case: `iso-iso2tex`. I posted more details in a previous answer: [emacs-accented-letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8880/make-emacs-speller-work-with-accented-modified-letters/8883#8883)

Answer (score 1):

starting from the work of Hosny, I created a script that can convert all Unicode to LaTeX

https://github.com/mennucc/unicode2latex

It will convert accents, e.g. è → `{e} ; also multiple accents
ṩ →  \.{\d{s}} .

It will express fonts, e.g. ⅅ → \symbbit{D} .

It will convert math symbols, e.g. ∩ → \cap .

Note that to compile a file that uses a command such as  \symbbit{D}, you need to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` with `fontspec` and `unicode-math` packages

Answer (score 0):

Several tools exist. (Tools are collected from various answers from other users from this site.
Credit: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578471/do-exists-a-tool-from-unicode-to-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1455876_578471) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316817/convert-unicode-symbols-to-tex?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment773434_316817) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540299/250119)
)

### Standalone command-line tools

- [pandoc-unicode-math](https://github.com/marhop/pandoc-unicode-math)
- [pylatexenc](https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/latexencode/)
- [recode](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode)
- Several scripts floating on the Internet: [1](https://gist.github.com/yourcelf/6055894),  [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317974/250119), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316919/250119), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580132/5267751)

### Library

- [LaTeX::Recode](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::Recode) (Perl library)
- [pylatexenc](https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/latexencode/) (Python library)

#### Editor plugins

- Sublime Text plugin: https://github.com/neilanderson/UnicodeTeX
- Vim plugin: https://github.com/joom/latex-unicoder.vim
- Vim plugin: https://github.com/Konfekt/vim-latexencode
- Emacs plugin: https://gist.github.com/kbauer/e8fee6514d124d5961f51fd7ba571bfd

#### `recode` usage instruction

Usually, this will already be installed on your computer.

To use it, do something like this for example:

```
$ echo á | recode UTF-8..LaTeX
\'a
```

However, as shown in [the source code](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode/blob/master/src/lat1ltex.c#L32), only a very small number of characters is supported -- in particular, only characters in Latin1 encoding is supported.