# Convert pasted characters to LaTeX equivalent

Tags: unicode

I use Mac, OSX 10.11.5. When I paste text from pdf files to emacs (tex mode), I get characters like "∈", "Ω". I need to convert them to LaTex equivalents "\in" "\Omega". Any hint?

Comment: In case you are willing to change: In TeXstudio there is a function `Convert to LaTeX` which does exactly this.

Comment: Do you want to know how to convert `∈` into `\in` or if/how you could directly use `∈` in your `.tex` file?

Comment: I use plain latex. I need to convert unicode characters to their latex equivalents, in order to have a collection of ASCII tex files. I should like to use emacs or python

Comment: Then I think you could write a python script with a home-made lexicon as described [here on stackexchange](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13089373). I am not aware of a `special characters -> LaTeX command` lexicon, except [this one](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)... but I think you would prefer to make your own that you complete when needed!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Using suggestions form various editors (thanks a lot!) I implemented this solution, which is ok for me

```
#!/usr/bin/pythonw
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import re

# NOTE: literals enclosing backckslash are forced to raw using prefix r'...'
repldict = {'Ω':r'\Omega','?<8A><86>':r'\subseteq','?<8A><82>':r'\subset',
        '?<9F>?':'<','?<9F>?':'>',
        '?<88><88>':r'\in','?<97>':r'\times','?<80><99>':'*apostrofo*',
        'μ':r'\mu','λ':r'\lambda','?<86>':r'\phi',
        '?<86><92>':r'\rightarrow','·':r'\cdot','?<88>?':'||',
        '?<89>?':r'\le',
        '?<88><9E>':r'\infty','ε':r'\varepsilon','Φ':r'\Phi',
        '?<88><92>':r'-','?<80><9C>':r'``','?<80><9D>':r'"','?<80><94>':r'-'}
def replfunc(match):
return repldict[match.group(0)]

def main():
 regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in repldict))

 inFile = sys.argv[1]
 fin = open(inFile,'r')
 outFile = 'pdf2latexChars' + '.tex'
 fout = open(outFile, 'w')
 print 'inFile=' + inFile + '; outFile=' + outFile 

 for line in fin:
    fout.write(regex.sub(replfunc,line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in PHP. You should be able to do something like this in Python:

```
$string = "I want the Latex equivalent of Ω, Δ, etc.";
$string = str_replace(
array("Ω","Δ"),
array("$\Omega$", "$\Delta$"),
$string);
```

string variable will now be:
"I want the Latex equivalent of $\Omega$, $\Delta$, etc."

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, in my opinion.

Comment: Well, he mentioned that he would like to use Python to solve the problem. Using this as reference should be sufficient?