# Automatic conversion from tex to unicode

Tags: unicode, unicode-math, automation, auto-completion

I am increasingly working with XeLaTeX and stated using unicode characters instead of Latex command.
For instance, I use `→` instead of `\to` in my documents.

Now, I'd like my IDE to automatically convert `\to` to `→`, a bit in the sense of [this chrome plug-in](https://golopot.github.io/tex-to-unicode/).

I've searched in the [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/34551) question, but could not find which IDE support this feature, if any.

**Is there an IDE or a program that can perform this conversion "on the fly" for me?**

*ps: For the sake of clarity: I know I can look up the symbols [here](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/unimathsymbols.html) or [there](https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/TeX.html), and [am aware of some of the challenges](https://tug.org/tug2010/booklet/robertson/extended-abstract.pdf), [pros and cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87257/34551) of using unicode directly. I also know that [on-line services](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11532/34551) for this translation exist, and that [scripts to go the other way around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/316802/34551) have been discussed here. What I'm looking for is to automate this task in my IDE, not to question it.*

Comment: Everything old is new again! TeX, or plain TeX, takes the `\to` character in position {hex}19, as given on the mythological extended keyboard. See The TeXbook, starting at the bottom of page 368. In plain TeX, `$a ^^19 b$` still works as `$a \to b$`. It does not in LaTeX, but I think it might have a very long time ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert characters to LaTeX code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23410/how-to-convert-characters-to-latex-code)

Comment: @user202729 Despite that some of the converts like `recode` can be used also to convert from LaTeX to UTF8, the questions and most answers about converting *to* LaTeX code and *from* LaTeX code are IMHO different.

Comment: Sorry I misread. The correct duplicate should be [unicode - Convert LaTex accented characters to UTF8 equivalent with Python - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447766/convert-latex-accented-characters-to-utf8-equivalent-with-python) (but provided this one actually have more votes than the other one maybe we duplicate vote it backwards, although this one is newer so it should be fine either direction I think)

Answer (score 3):

This vim plugin https://github.com/joom/latex-unicoder.vim provides a key binding `C-l` to transform latex commands to their utf-8 equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

This emacs pluging https://gist.github.com/kbauer/e8fee6514d124d5961f51fd7ba571bfd is an

> Autohotkey-script for converting LaTeX-like input to unicode characters. "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U" toggles it on and off.