# Do exists a tool from unicode to LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, tools

I am currently looking for a **tool** that converts a Unicode code to TeX/LaTeX. Actually I have not found anything.

There are many tools on the web that transform a symbol from LaTeX to Unicode but not vice versa.

In case there is no such tool, I have thought this: is it possible to generate a LaTeX code that transforms a *unicode symbol* into LaTeX commands? For example I have alfa in unicode and I would to obtain `\alpha`.

I can only use `pdfLaTeX` to compile my `.tex` file.

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean, if you have a unicode string such as `α → β` you can just use it as it is in luatex or xetex and unicode-math no conversion is needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I not like LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. My preferite it is pdfLaTeX :-).

Comment: well you can use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to make it work in pdftex too if you wish.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited now and I am agree totally with you. For the tags I have thought that `expl3` may be useful to create a transformation code. And the `latextools` tag referred to something specific from unicode to latex. Now I remove them.

Comment: If you hover over the tag it tells you what they are for. latextools is a plugin for the sublime text editor which I guess you are not using.

Comment: There is a pandoc filter that can convert unicode math to latex symbols: [pandoc-unicode-math](https://github.com/marhop/pandoc-unicode-math). You can extend its symbol list to include all the characters you need

Comment: [pylatexenc](https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/latexencode/) seems to be able to do the conversion as well

Comment: ...and [LaTeX::Recode](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::Recode)

Comment: @DG' Hi, and thank you for your link. For me it is hard to understand to install or to understand the  pandoc-unicode-math :-(....I don't understand how to use them if I don't see practical examples :-(

Comment: @DG' For me it's like understanding the Arabic language :-)

Comment: ...and [tex-conversions.py](https://gist.github.com/yourcelf/6055894)

Comment: @DG' I am not able, sorry :-(

Comment: ...and [recode](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode)

Comment: Your problem is: "I can only use pdfLaTeX to compile my .tex file." It means that you want to use 30 years old software. If you can use up-to-date TeX engines then you needn't convert from Unicode to TeX because modern TeX understands Unicode.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue actually is, there has been a lot of answers in the comments. Pylatexenc has installation instruction in https://pypi.org/project/pylatexenc/ , and example how to use it in https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . See also for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/23833666/5267751

Comment: @user202729 How this tool work?

Comment: example how to use it (and what does it do) is in https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest .