# How can I insert a ¿ character in a latex file

Tags: symbols, spanish

After a couple of hours looking at Google for a solution, I arrived here for help. So, please!

I just want to insert a `¿` symbol.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Try `\textquestiondown`, see also [How do I look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

Comment: [Here is what DeTeXify found](http://i.stack.imgur.com/waFup.png)...

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't think this is exactly a duplicate, at least not from "How do I look up a symbol". In this case the OP is asking for a Spanish symbol which can be input directly from the keyboard once `inputenc` is loaded with the apppropriate encoding. The answers to the other question don't apply here.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Perhaps the related [How to use Spanish accents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33628/how-to-use-spanish-accents) then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way, in text mode (I don't think it is needed in math mode), is to write:

```
?`
```

PS: I would have written the above as a comment but I haven't been able to do that because the needed character is the one used for writing code...

Comment: karlkoeller -- the backtick notation is only available in ot1 encoding; thus your answer is inconsistent with all the others'...  the other possibility in ot1, even simpler on the fingers, is `>` for `\textexclamdown` and `<` for `\textquestiondown` ... (personally i would go for utf-8 if i were writing an inflected language.)

Comment: @wasteofspace 1. Sorry for the answer, I just wanted to post a comment. 2. I know that it is only available in OT1 (anyway I didn't know about `<` and `>`). 3. I switched to utf-8 years ago, I was just remembering the way I was used to write such 'strange' characters without utf-8.

Answer (score 7):

Use `inputenc` and input the character directly from your keyboard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

¿

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, make sure your editor is also set to Unicode. If your editor encoding is set to `ISO-8859-1` then load `inputenc` with the `latin1` option:

```
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```