# XeLaTeX hang when using specific math symbols

Tags: xetex, errors, symbols, amsmath, unicode-math

I am using XeLaTeX in conjunction with `amsmath` and `unicode-math` for my reports. After a while, I ran into a weird problem in which compilation would just hang indefinitely. I found out the culprit was me using `\pm` or `\times` symbols (there might of course be others) in a math environment.

Does anybody know why this occurs and how to fix it?

Edit: Okay, after stripping down my list of packages I observed that compilation breaks as soon as I use the `inputenc` package, for example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec} % XeLaTeX required!
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % <------ This package breaks compilation!!!
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Myriad Pro}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\begin{document}
$\pm$
\end{document}
```

Not being able to use this package would be a real shame though, because we dutch people sure like our accents at times...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Can you please provide a mwe as having just tried the most simple case, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have added an example using every package that is in my default set-up and does not compile.

Comment: Are you sure, your math Font provides these symbols? I can't compile your example (which is not minimal), due to missing fonts. I think it might be your fonts. Furthermore: Can you try to eliminate a few packages, so that your example is minimal?

Comment: Yes, Asana Math is a Unicode complete math font, you can download it as a package:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/Asana-Math
I now stripped my MWE to an actual minimal example, and concluded `inputenc` breaks compilation.

Comment: If you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you should *never* load the `inputenc` package (and usually not the `fontenc` package.)  Your file should be saved at UTF-8.  See [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736).  Also, if you are using IPA characters with XeLaTeX you may run into problems using TIPA; instead use a Unicode font that has IPA.  See [Using TeX for writing papers on linguistics](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36542).

Comment: You made my day sir, if you would make an answer out of your comment I would mark it as answer when I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you should never load the `inputenc` package (and usually not the `fontenc` package.) Your file should be saved at UTF-8. See

- [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736)

Also, if you are using IPA characters with XeLaTeX you may run into problems using TIPA; instead use a Unicode font that has IPA. See

- [How to use phonetic IPA characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36542)