# Capacity exceeded error

Tags: biblatex, capacity

I am using MacTex 2016 on a Mac (El Captain 10.11.2). My text editor is TexStudio 2.11.0 and all my packages have been updated (TeX live Utility 1.24).

Since I updated MacTex from version 2015 to version 2016, I constantly get the same error when compiling : in a file containing references, when I compile with XeLateX the first time, I get an error about exceeded capacity right where I have an \textcite or \autocite command (the following lines are just warnings) :

TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. This book \autocite{adams}
'firstinits' option is deprecated, use 'giveninits' instead.
inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
Patching footnotes failed.
Conflicting options.
Add \usepackage{fontspec} to the(frenchb.ldf) preamble of your document,

This file.tex would work just fine before I updated MacTex, I would compile with XeLateX, then bibtex, then XeLatex twice. But before trying to desinstall 2016 and come back to 2015 (if I am ever able to download it somewhere...), I would like to understand what I am doing wrong, and obviously I'm doing something VERY wrong.

```
\documentclass{book}
\title{Chapitre2}
\makeindex
\date{}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/Users/MyName/Documents/Latex/biblio.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, calc, shapes.misc, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

bla bla

This book \autocite{adams} is awesome.

Another awesome book : \textcite{arnason}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I know there are a lot of packages, but since some of them are incompatible, maybe that could be the problem.
And here are the two references I'm refering to from my bib file :

```
@Book{adams,
  title =     {Faroese: a language course for beginners},
  publisher = {Stiðin},
  year =      {2014},
  author =    {Adams, Jonathan and Petersen, Hjalmar P.},
  address =   {T\'{o}rshavn},
  type =      {Book}
}

@Book{arnason,
  title =     {The phonology of Icelandic and Faroese},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  year =      {2011},
  author =    {\'{A}rnason, Kristj\'{a}n},
  address =   {Oxford; New York},
  type =      {Book}
}
```

If I forgot something important, please ask.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There were a few minor problems, but I can compile it. You cannot compile this very file?

Comment: You can easily reduce the example by commenting out packages and removing them if you still get the error. It is just mechanical.

Comment: Unless you manually deleted your MacTeX 2015 distribution, it is still on your computer, and you can switch between it and the 2016 version using the TeX Live Utility (see the Change Default TeX Live Version item in the Configure menu).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you :) I looked on forums and tried different things and I always ended up with the same error.

Comment: @cfr I did! But I need all of these packages. I tried to order them differently so they would not conflict, without success.

Comment: &Alan I removed the 2015 version -_- I thought maybe there is an overwriting problem somewhere... I prefer to keep an updated system, but if erasing the 2016 version was the only solution, I would do it. The answers you and egreg proposed look good, I am trying them right now.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need them all to reproduce the problem. You don't need them all in your MWE! Also, you don't need to load them all separately and would be better to load some differently as I suggested in a comment.

Comment: @cfr I will try this in my next MWE then

Comment: No, there is never a problem installing multiple years of TeX Live. They will not interfere with each other, and on the Mac it's really easy (and sometimes very useful) to switch between years.  But as you've seen there are solutions to your problem that won't require any reinstallation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in `\automath` of `gb4e`, together with the fact that `biblatex` uses an internal key with an underscore `_` in its name.

This makes TeX enter a loop that ends with the dreaded “TeX capacity exceeded” message.

If you want to use `gb4e` and `biblatex` together, you need to issue `\noautomath`.

Other problems in your preamble are

1. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
2. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
3. `\usepackage{times}`

These should be removed and

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

should be issued. If you want a Times like font, declare

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
```

Here's an updated version of your preamble that fixes the issue.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{adams,
  title =     {Faroese: a language course for beginners},
  publisher = {Stiðin},
  year =      {2014},
  author =    {Adams, Jonathan and Petersen, Hjalmar P.},
  address =   {T\'{o}rshavn},
  type =      {Book}
}

@Book{arnason,
  title =     {The phonology of Icelandic and Faroese},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  year =      {2011},
  author =    {\'{A}rnason, Kristj\'{a}n},
  address =   {Oxford; New York},
  type =      {Book}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  citestyle=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2,
%  firstinits=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, calc, shapes.misc, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\noautomath

\begin{document}
\title{Chapitre2}
\date{}

bla bla

This book \autocite{adams} is awesome.

Another awesome book : \textcite{arnason}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to make the document self-contained. Use your own `.bib` database. You should consider using Biber instead of BibTeX.

[image]

If TeX Gyre Termes is not installed as a system font, declare it in the following way:

```
\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]
```

Comment: Might be good to recommend replacing `tipa` if the OP is using XeLaTeX anyway? Also `colortbl` can go if `table` is added for `xcolor` and `graphicx` can be removed. Do you happen to know why Biblatex recommends `xpatch`?

Comment: Thanks egreg! I tried your MWE in my TexStudio and I get a new error : fontspec error: `"font-not-found" The font "TeX Gyre Termes" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>. \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}.` On my Tex Live utility, I can see that tex-gyre is installed (which is the required package for this font, if I understood correctly). If I take this line out, then I get this error : `Undefined control sequence. \end`
I still need a little bit more research to get your solution to work, but it's helping since I don't get the "capacity exceeded" error anymore!

Comment: @Islenska You have to install TeX Gyre Termes as a system font, or do a more complicated call. I'll add the way for setting it.

Comment: It worked, the font is perfect :) Also, I changed backend=bibtex to biber and set biber as my default bibliography tool in the settings. References appear correctly in the text now. However I still get the Undefined control sequence. \end error. If I take out the \printbibliography command then it compiles fine... Ps: I saw this post (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158731/undefined-control-sequence-at-enddocument) and did what you advised. It is not the problem.

Comment: @Islenska Sorry, but I get no error. Try retyping the last lines.

Comment: @egreg I copied/pasted it in a new file and it worked oO Thank you very much for all your advice!

Answer (score 4):

The solution that egreg proposes requires  you to turn off the `\automath` feature (which allows use of `_` and `^` in text mode).  Since this is really a quite useful feature for linguists, here's a solution (due to David Carlisle) which will solve the problem and also allow you to keep using `\automath`. It is likely that this will be included in the next release of `gb4e` but that hasn't happened at time of writing.

As cfr mentions in her comment to egreg, it's generally not a great idea to use TIPA if you are using XeLaTeX. Instead use a font with phonetic symbols and enter them directly into your source. See:

- [How to use phonetic IPA characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36542/2693)
- [Typesetting phonetic symbols: Unicode or tipa?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224164/2693)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{adams,
  title =     {Faroese: a language course for beginners},
  publisher = {Stiðin},
  year =      {2014},
  author =    {Adams, Jonathan and Petersen, Hjalmar P.},
  address =   {T\'{o}rshavn},
  type =      {Book}
}

@Book{arnason,
  title =     {The phonology of Icelandic and Faroese},
  publisher = {Oxford University Press},
  year =      {2011},
  author =    {\'{A}rnason, Kristj\'{a}n},
  address =   {Oxford; New York},
  type =      {Book}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  citestyle=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2,
%  firstinits=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\let\gbtmp_
\protected\def_{\ifincsname\string_\else\expandafter\gbtmp\fi}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\noautomath

\begin{document}
\title{Chapitre2}
\date{}

bla bla

This book \autocite{adams} is awesome.

Another awesome book : \textcite{arnason}.

And you can use subscripts_{a} in text mode!

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks Alan, your alternative for \noautomath works just fine. However, I get the same error that I mentioned to egreg : the font Tex Gyre Termes is not found. If I take this line out (\setmainfont{}), this compiles without an error. I prefer Times-like fonts aesthetically, but well... I also like a working compilation :)

Comment: So I added egreg's font call to your MWE and it compiled without an error. Both your answers are working perfectly! I am still considering using something else than tipa, thanks for the links!

Comment: @Islenska Yes, the issue about the font is a separate one; the basic code assumes you have the font installed as a system font which is the default mode for XeLaTeX. Since egreg's answer shows how to use use the TeX version of the font, I won't add it here.