# TeX capacity exceeded trying to load biblatex (using MikTex 2.9.7206 and TexStudio 2.12.22) on Windows 7

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, biber, miktex2.9

Trying to finish a dissertation here. When clicking Build & View in TexStudio, I get an Error Message plus a Warning Message:

> logreq.def error line 8 Tex capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack
>   size=10000]. ...Container{requests}{(internal | external)*}
>
> leipzig.sty warning line 503 Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc'undefined(Font) using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead

The error is evidently caused by the mere attempt to load biblatex. It occurs even if no \addbibresource or \printbibliography are called within the document, and even if no settings are specified within the \usepackage call. Both errors (including the warning message) disappear if I simply disable the line that loads biblatex. Here's my main.tex (the individual chapters are separate files and clearly irrelevant):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{tabu}
 \usepackage{float} 
 \usepackage{tipa}
 \usepackage{leipzig}
 \usepackage{gb4e}
 \usepackage{caption} 
 \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex} % Deactivating this line enables the document to compile without errors.
% \addbibresource{sources.bib}
 \noautomath
\begin{document}

\author{My Anonymized Name}
\title{My Anonymized Title}
\date{October 2020}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\mainmatter
\include{./TeX_files/chapter01}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter02}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter03}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter04}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter05}

\backmatter
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

% \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make this self contained. We do not have access to `sources.bib` or the included tex files (are the included tex files even relevant)

Comment: Please cut it down to a MWE (Minimal (non-)Working Example). Without the included files, all we can do is wild guessing. Delete included files and packages until it stops failing. Delete intermediate/auxiliary files each time, a corrupted one can also be the cause here.

Comment: Move `\usepackage{gb4e}` behind biblatex, this package is dangerous and should be loaded late . Or alternatively move the `\noautomath` directly behind the package. That will prevent the interferences too.

Comment: Calling `usepackage{gb4e}` and `\noautomath` dead last, as Ulrike suggests, has solved the problem.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321119/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101300/35864. The former is spot on as a duplicate.

Comment: moewe: Yes, those two threads do deal with the same problem. However, their titles were not sufficiently specific to come up when I googled for answers -- they don't give the exact wording of the error message or specify that it was the attempt to load biblatex that triggered the problem.