# Introducing special signs to cls file

Tags: characters, documentclass-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to type special/accented letters in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex)

Can sameone provide some suggestion how to introduce special signs to cls file? I had tried to avoid this problem by trying to define new variable : \def\@abc and typing my test with \abc{text} but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "special signs"? Do you mean using reserved characters like `@,#,$` etc. in text? If so, most of them can be used by escaping them with \.

Comment: By special signs I mean diacritic signs.

Comment: Make sure your source document is encoded in UTF-8 and if using pdfLaTeX use the `inputenc` package with the `[utf8]` option, and a font encoding that supports the characters.  Or compile using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with no `inputenc`.  In both cases you just enter the characters directly into your source.

Comment: @AlanMunn I don't have problem with compiling such signs in tex file. I have problem introducing such signs in class file. The problem arises when I want to compile tex file of such class. Text with diacritic sigh which is introduced in tex file source is fine but text which is introduced in cls file isn't. I hope that I presented my problem clearly enough - I'm don't have much practice working with LateX.

Comment: Ok.  Now the question is clearer (you might want to add your last comment to the question itself.)  One simple solution would be to use `\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (unless XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is used) in your class file.  This would make the class file dependent on a particular encoding, though.  If you don't want to do that, then you can use macros for the diacritics. (See the  Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List for those.) (`texdoc symbols` should probably find it.)

Answer (score 5):

While it is possible to force the encoding of the class file, it is probably better not to, as not doing so makes it easier to use the class file with documents that are in different encodings.

There is usually relatively little fixed text in a class file, so it should not be too hard to write all such text in "classic" LaTeX markup, just using ASCII input.

So rather than use `[[é]]` use `[[\'e]]`  This will then work whether the document using the class uses `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`