# installed package not running

Tags: packages, texshop

I have TexShop installed on my Mac and I need to use the Slovak language in my LaTeX documents. Through the TexLive Utility, I found out that I have `collection-langczechslovak` installed, but when I write it in the preamble of the document, it says that this file was not found. 
Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, this collection is just the appropriate files for `babel`, in which case you just need to add

```
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
```

to your document, and use appropriate fonts for Slovak. See the `babel` documentation for more information (you can to that from within TeXShop by using the "Show Help for Package" menu item in the Help menu.

For font information see: [How to type special/accented letters in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8857/2693)