# How to type "Erdos"?

Tags: typewriter

How to type "Erdos"? In paricular, the "O" . Thanks ahead.
[image]

Comment: The double acute accent can also be produced with `\H{}` for non-unicode input, so `Erd\H{o}s`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using Unicode characters and [LaTeX accents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    Paul Erdős\\
    Paul Erd\H{o}s
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]