# TeXmaker and Polish letters

Tags: texmaker, input-encodings

I have a problem with encoding Polish letters in TeXmaker. What I mean by this is that:

- when I write Polish letters in TeXmaker they are visible as Polish letters: ą, ę, ć and so on
- yet after compilation what I get in dvi or pdf are just question marks
- similarly, if I open tex file written in TeXmaker and containing Polish letters in WinEdt, what I get are question marks as well
- if I produce a file containing polish letters in TeXmaker, close it and re-open in TeXmaker — again question marks

I know there must be some problem with encoding, yet I have no idea how to solve it.

> The question has been marked as duplicate, however the original answer which was pointed to me does not concern the problem of Polish signs in TeXmaker and in a source file. Texenthusiast's answer below helped me to solve that problem as well.

Comment: `Options`-->`configure texmaker`-->`Editor`-->`Editor font encoding`-->`utf-8` Press `Ok` and restart texmaker. Always use `unicode`. may be see if this is relevant http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html  "Installing the ibus-qt package is recommended to avoid some trouble with accentued characters on some linux distributions (for Qt4 versions only)". Finally Now start typing polish and save and run `pdflatex` to verify pdf file.

Comment: BTW one should add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble for compiling the `.tex` file with unicode characters.

Comment: @texenthusiast I have followed your instruction, i.e. I set TeXmaker to utf-8. When I include <code>\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}</code> in the preamble, then I get very strange looking symbols for polish letters. Without it I get the following error for every polish letter: <code>! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ś not set up for use with LaTeX.</code> However, when I re-open file, I still can see polish letters in the file.

Comment: @texenthusiast The problem was hidden in the first line <code>%&platex --translate-file=cp1250pl</code> placed before <code>\begin{document}</code> (I use MikTeX). After I have deleted it, everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Alan Only partially, since I also experienced problem with encoding in TeXmaker itself. But your link will be very useful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @MadHatter: The TeX file itself must be saved in UTF-8, or if it was already saved in another encoding, it must be _converted_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1**: Change Editor Encoding `utf-8` that supports unicode characters

Close all opened `.tex` files inside Texmaker and  now go to `Options`-->`Configure texmaker`-->`Editor`-->`Editor font encoding`-->`utf-8` Press `Ok` and restart texmaker to take the encoding into effect.

Relevant info for Linux users about `ibus-qt` package

http://xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html "Installing the ibus-qt package is recommended to avoid some trouble with accentued characters on some linux distributions (for Qt4 versions only)".

**Step 2**: Now [How to type special/accented letters in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex) by loading [`inputenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) and [`fontenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) in Preamble.

Add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % `utf8` option to match Editor encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to the preamble before compiling the `.tex` file with unicode characters to correctly reflect in `.pdf` file . Finally now start typing polish language with above preamble, save and run `pdflatex file-name` to get required `pdf` file

Alternative to **Step 2** some people might prefer using `xelatex` unicode LaTeX engine by loading [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) with more font options [compared to pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-xelatex).

**Note**: Use a cross-platform unicode LaTeX editor from the [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)