# How to write accents in LaTeX?

Tags: accents

I need to cite the journal "Sankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics" in a paper.  I would like to draw the ā character properly (i.e., I'd prefer, if possible, to avoid using some hack, such as `\bar` or `\overline`).

*Question*: How do I properly write ā in LaTeX?

I didn't have luck with [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) (after several attempts in both in capital and lowercase) nor The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List (searching the file for "ā" and "india" revealed no hits).

Comment: See [How to type special/accented letters in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8859/5764)

Comment: the information actually is in the comprehensive list, under "text-mode accents" (table 17, p.14).  it does help, though, when using this list, to already be familiar with quite a bit of the terminology used.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can write the macron using `\=<character>`;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Sankhy\=a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the record, here's a table I wrote some time ago, containing (I think) all the accents provided by LaTeX (the original names were in Spanish; I used the English names I found on the web, but let me know if there's any mistakes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}clcc@{}} 
    \toprule & &
    \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Example}\\ 
    \cmidrule(l){3-4}
    Definition &
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{Description} &
    Input &
    Output \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(r){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
    \lstinline+\'{<character>}+ & acute accent & \lstinline+\'{a}+ & \'{a}\\
    \lstinline+\`{<character>}+ & grave accent & \lstinline+\`{a}+ & \`{a}\\
    \lstinline+\"{<character>}+ & umlaut or dieresis & \lstinline+\"{u}+ & \"{u}\\
    \lstinline+\c{<character>}+ & cedilla &\lstinline+\c{c}+ & \c{c}\\
    \lstinline+\={<character>}+ & macron & \lstinline+\={a}+ & \={a}\\ 
    \lstinline+\b{<character>}+ & bar under &\lstinline+\b{a}+ & \b{a}\\ 
    \lstinline+\u{<character>}+ & breve accent &\lstinline+\u{a}+ & \u{a}\\ 
    \lstinline+\v{<character>}+ & há\v{c}ek &\lstinline+\v{a}+ & \v{a}\\
    \lstinline+\~{<character>}+ & tilde & \lstinline+\~{n}+ & \~{n}\\
    \lstinline+\^{<character>}+ & circumflex accent & \lstinline+\^{o}+ & \^{o}\\ 
    \lstinline+\.{<character>}+ & dot accent &\lstinline+\.{a}+ & \.{a}\\ 
    \lstinline+\d{<character>}+ & dot-under accent &\lstinline+\d{a}+ & \d{a}\\ 
    \lstinline+\r{<character>}+ & ring &\lstinline+\r{a}+ & \r{a}\\
    \lstinline+\H{<character>}+ & long Hungarian umlaut &\lstinline+\H{a}+ & \H{a}\\
    \lstinline+\k{<character>}+ & ogonek &\lstinline+\k{a}+ & \k{a}\\ 
    \lstinline+\t{<character>}+ & tie-after accent &\lstinline+\t{oo}+ & \t{oo}\\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  } 

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **egreg** mentions in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163716/how-do-i-properly-write-in-latex/163717#comment375917_163717), Accents over the "i" deserve special mention: `i , `\'i`, `\^i` and `\"i` produce the desired accent, but `\i`  must be used for the others, for instance `\={\i}` or `\v{\i}`.

Of course, some of the accents can be obtained loading the `inputenc` package and typing them directly from the keyboard.

Thanks to **Mico** for [suggesting the addition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163716/how-do-i-properly-write-in-latex/163717?noredirect=1#comment376005_163717) of the ogonek.

Comment: Even if you can access it on your keyboard, the character is not set up for use as a unicode character through `inputenc` so this would still be the out-of-the-box way to get the accent.

Comment: @cfr Yes, you're right. I was just checking that. I'll delete the superfluous part from my answer.

Comment: Will the character be "selectable" in the pdf?

Comment: @pluton some of them will, some won't. The first four tigether with the tilde, the circumflex and the ring will be "copyable" from the PDF; the others won't.

Comment: Why is the ring uppercase?

Comment: @PålGD A small typo in the table. I used a lowercase "a" in the input part, but an uppercase "A" in the output. I'll fix it. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: You might add that the common accents over “i” can be input as `\\`i`, `\'i`, `\^i` and `\"i`, but `\i` must be used for the others (for instance `\={\i}`).

Comment: @egreg It's a good suggestion. I'll add it in some minutes. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to nominated the "ogonek" symbol, e.g., `\k{a}`, for inclusion in this fine table.

Comment: @Mico +1 for nominating Polish "ogonek" (i.e., roughly speaking, "small tail"). Polak bez ogonka / W pisaniu się błąka (It means: `A Pole without "ogonek" strays in his writing`. Alas, without rhymes in English version).

Answer (score 5):

Use the unicode character!

With pdflatex you then have to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, with lualatex or xetex `\usepackage{fontspec}`.
Your source file has to be encoded like this of course.

#### pdflatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Sankhyā
\end{document}
```

#### xelatex or lualatex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Sankhyā
\end{document}
```

#### Character input

There are several ways to directly input unicode characters that are not on your keyboard.

- **editors** provide tools for it, e.g. with vim you can press ctrl + k and insert a key kombination, e.g. `a*` for α.
- **Compose Key**. Most Unix Systems provide a Compose Key, that lets you input characters by pressing certain key combination if you press a special key. If you define `Caps lock` to be your compose key, you can type `caps lock` `a` `-` to get `ā`. Most of these combinations are rather intuitive, so you do not have to lokk them up. E.g. you get → by pressing `compose` `-` `>` or € by pressing `compose` `C` `=`.
- **enter unicode hex code**, for windows press `alt` `u` and enter the unicode hex code, for e.g. ubuntu press `ctrl alt u` and enter the hex code. The unicode postion of ā is U+0101.

Comment: For Mac OS X (US Extended keyboard), `ALT-a + letter`: `āēīōūȳs̄ḹṝḡ`

Comment: You have to be careful with Unicode. There are issues with `᾿` (Greek psili) that is turned into an accented ligature where it is not supposed to, e.g. Κατ᾿ ἐμαυτοῦ