# Special chararacter writing

Tags: characters

I need to write a special character similar as when you write "\aa", i.e., a with circle above, but I need the same for "u", i.e., u with a circle above, how to do it?

Comment: `\r{u}` but this is quite a basic thing: almost all guides cover 'commands for accents'.

Comment: See this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163717/3954 for a table with available accents.

Comment: @JosephWright Do you think this could be closed as duplicate of this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163716/3954 ? The answer gives a list of available accents (including the ring), although the question there asked for a different accent.

Comment: @user70214 Hopefully the suggested dupe helps here: probably it needs a more general title to aid searching!