How to get the accent grave in è right using biblatex, biber and Latin10?
Which sign combination at a German keyboard has to be used to get the accent grave in è correct while \'e gives the é?

Please specify which operating system you use. (It presumably matters if you use Windows, MacOS, or some other OS.)

I use Windows 11.

see https://allthings.how/how-to-type-accents-in-windows-11/#typing-accents-with-alt-codes-on-windows-11 and https://whileint.com/de/tech/stephane/how-to-type-accents-on-windows/

or if you are looking for a latex solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/accents/info\

It's not clear if you're looking for a way to use ascii characters to get that output (such as in samcarter's second comment and your answer) or if you're asking how to use a standard German keyboard (and Windows 11) so that you can type è in your source file (such as in samcarter's first comment).

Either a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163716/36296  or off topic and better suited for superuser.com . Not clear enough to decide which one it is.

From the duplicate: \`e (the backtick accent, usually located under the tilde next to the number 1) will output è.

It took me a while to figure out an editor that even supports latin10, but I found one and recoded my test file (it's at https://gist.github.com/moewew/958a288116060754f3d9eb7acfeb1cc2). I still get https://i.sstatic.net/zOdypuv5.png. I strongly recommend you switch to UTF-8, it's the de facto standard encoding nowadays and supports most characters and is supported by all good modern editors.

I got it:
\usepackegage{amsmath}
$\grave{e}$
works even in bibliograpies using biblatex

If you have any mercy for your readers, don't do that.

Oh no. copy & paste è instead.

To give a rationale to the above comments: $ should be for math, not for italics or accents.  If you have text, it should be entered as text, not as math.

@Ulrike: Does not work under bibtex.

@samcarter: Alternatives?

@PeterZilkens The ones I linked to in comments below your question

@PeterZilkens Why do you care if it works in bibtex, didn't you just ask multiple questions about biblatex?

with bibtex you can use \`e, but with biblatex/biber è should be fine.

I have only ', \` and \´ are not accepted by biblatex.

Please delete so you do not confuse future readers. Using math mode for a textual accent in a bibliography is completely wrong

@PeterZilkens Assuming UTF-8 encoding of your .tex file and .bib file and no inputenc declaration to the contrary, both \`e and è will produce "è" in the output and both \'e and é will produce é. Only in .bib files you need(ed) to wrap escapes for non-ASCII characters in an additional pair of curly braces: {\`e} and {\'e}. This was needed because BibTeX can only deal with ASCII characters: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/35864. With Biber you should use the non-ASCII character directly anyway: No additional braces needed.

The math trick shown here should not be needed at all. On my computer the following document https://gist.github.com/moewew/c6b08a5b5de42ed9cee2ea00cd52ab01 (when saved in UTF-8 encoding, which is by now probably standard in most modern editors) will compile without error to the following output https://i.sstatic.net/v8WRHy3o.png

@moewe: It doesn't using TeXstudio and my machine ( find system description here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732472/migration-of-thesis-written-in-documentclassdissonlinelatex-to-documentclass)

@PeterZilkens Have you tried the exact document I posted? Did you save it as UTF-8? Exactly what kind of errors do you get?

@Moewe: I use this math trick now and it works. My aim is to get the right output. Without that trick it would be a nicer coding style.

Many thx everybody for their discussion and help. Now the .pdf-output looks like it should -- after a one week struggle. ;-)

I understand that you are mainly concerned with the result in the PDF and not so much with writing code that other people approve of. And I know that we need to choose our battles wisely, but I think $\grave{e}$ instead of è or \`e is an extremely bad idea. For starters the "e" you get will be in math mode, which by default is italic, so word with "è" would potentially change font just for the "è" that will look very weird. If we can't change your mind, we can hopefully at least dissuade others.

@PeterZilkens Using strange "tricks" was one source of most of your problems (e.g. using a not recommended trick to try to get an empty line). So do you really think that using one more such not recommended tricks is a good idea? BTW: The editor, i.e. using TeXstudio, is not relevant for the correctness of code. The input moewe told you in his comment and is also shown in the answers to the duplicate question works independently of the editor.
