# European Accents not showing correctly

Tags: fonts, accents, input-encodings, font-encodings

When i type " é " directly with the appointed key, or use a key combination of "´ + e" (where I press the ´ first, the character doesn't show up, and then I pres e and the accent appears) it doesn't show in my pdf when i print for feedback.

i'm using TexMaker and have a AZERTY-keyboard (belgian).
I've tried to look at a lot of answers already involving UTC8 and `\inputenc` but with UTC8 the document lay-out just looks horrible... and with inputenc I only get a lot of weird symbols instead of the accented character.

Any way i can fix this without using \´e?

Comment: Read this answer and then explain clearly what you have actually done. [How to type special/accented letters in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8857). If you are using `pdflatex` you need to load both the `inputenc` package (with the correct encoding for your file) and the `fontenc` package (with the `[T1]` encoding) plus a font that contains the relevant glyphs.

Comment: I use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and insert the à è ì ò ù in the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use this preamble:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = it
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
```

Of course, you have to change `[italian]` and `it` if you use another language.

**EDIT**

As suggest by [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard), if you do not use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`:

- Words containing accented characters can not be automatically hyphenated.
- You can not properly copy/paste such words from the output (DVI/PS/PDF).
- Characters like the pipe sign, less than and greater sign give unexpected results in text.

And the `\usepackage{lmodern}` implement the "Latin Modern" font. Try it and see the difference.

Comment: Somehow this works without making the text al weird. Thanks Giacomo! :).

Comment: Nonetheless you should add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}` if you want to stick to fonts very similar to the default Computer Modern.

Comment: @Bernard, I have add your informations. Thanks.