# Beamer Presentation compile error

Tags: beamer, errors, amsmath, mathtools, bm

I'm trying to do a presentation doing a Beamer template.

I've loaded the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Everything else is according to the template with minor changes like instead \date{\today} I put \date{June 20, 2016}, or instead of \frametitle{Overview} I put \frametitle{Sumário}.

I'm trying to compile this with texmaker, but I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\mathbf' already defined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help....
```

I've yet to use that command in the presentation, and the line texmaker indicates as the beginning of problematic section is right at the start, i.e. `\begin{document}`

I know that if I comment out the bm package the problem goes away, but I've used this combination of packages in documents before without any problem.

Why is this happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a combination of `beamer`, `bm` and `lmodern`. For example `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
s
\end{document}` will produce the error, swapping the order of `bm` and `lmodern` and the error goes away.

Comment: What's the reason for `\usepackage{lmodern}`?

Comment: @egreg the reason is I would like to write accented letters

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. What has `lmodern` to do with accented letters?

Comment: @egreg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. This is `beamer`, remember. However, the advice is misleading. Anyway, loading the packages in different order solves the issue: load `bm` last. I suggest the order `inputenc`, `fontenc`, `babel` if needed, `lmodern`, `mathtools` and finally `bm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the package loading order. Note that `graphicx` is already loaded by `beamer`.

On the other hand, loading `lmodern` is not needed, unless you're on MiKTeX and don't have a working installation of the CM-Super fonts.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

Some text and math:
\[
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=n\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)(n+1)
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without a proper MWE, this is the best help I can offer: invoking `professionalfonts` produces no such error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sam, what's an MWE?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea., it's a "minimal working example"; check here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that Basically, it's code that shows the problem as concisely as possible that begins with a `documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.