# Accented letters disappear in LaTeX

Tags: accents

I am trying to translate a piece of French material (in English) and here is my codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage{paracol}


\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{sloppypar}
 \begin{paracol}{2}  
 1. Il y a plus de 50 ans que l'ingénieur Heaviside introduisit  ses règles de calcul symbolique, dans un mémoire audacieux où des calculs mathématiques fort peu justifiés sont utilisés pour la solution de problèmes de physique.\\ 
 \switchcolumn

 \end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

But when I run the codes in TeXStudio, the accented letters completely disappear. (For instance, "ingénieur" in the first sentence becomes "ingnieur".)

[image]

Is there a quicker way to fix this than manully typing the accented letters as in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8859/5590)?

Comment: Not to be rude, but does the answer below that not help you?

Comment: Add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to your preamble, as suggested in the first answer in [How to type special/accented letters in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8857/5764) (that you link to).

Comment: @Au101: You are absolutely right. The answer in the link I gave is the first one I read and I didn't try the one below it. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @Werner: Since I didn't know what `utf8` is, I didn't try that one. Stupid me. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Jack No worries, it happens. UTF-8 is a character encoding. It's a standard. It's a standard that says the hexadecimal number 20AC is € for example. So the point is, if we all follow the standard, then 20AC on my computer, on your computer and on Werner's computer will display the right character, assuming our font uses UTF-8. UTF-8 is pretty ubiquitous and supports all of Unicode's code points. It's basically a way of ensuring that when I type € I see €, you see €, everyone sees €

Comment: @Au101: thanks a lot for the information`:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your document is in UTF-8, then insert

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

It it is in Latin-1 then replace utf8 with latin1