# How can I write the date in french?

Tags: date

I use the following command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
```

but the date is just shown as "16 fvrier 2017" missing a "é", I wonder how should I deal with this problem?

What's more, the title of content misses also a "è":
[image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`if unless you want a non-default font.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8858/36296

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and  `\usepackage{lmodern}` solved the problem.

> @Bernhard: Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage{lmodern}if unless you
>   want a non-default font.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\today 
\end{document}
```

You can also customize your date format with `\newdateformat{mydateformat}{\monthname~\THEYEAR}`. Command `\mydateformat\today`.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Your second Question: Answer for table of content

[image]

You only need a section. Formatting pagecounter is optional.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}  
 \title{Sur l'Extension Galoisienne de Degr\'e Infini}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\maketitle \tableofcontents 
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}   
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Date}
Today: \today 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's more, I just noticed that the title of content is shown as "Table des matires" missing a "è", how should I deal with this?

Comment: Can you add your code as MWE?  http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\title{Sur l'Extension Galoisienne de Degr\'e Infini}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\end{document}

Here is my code, it doesn't work

Comment: @Victor Chen . You need at least one `\section`.  I expand the answer to that. See above. It works.

Comment: I've tried, but just as the picture shows, I doesn't work. I don't know why :(

Comment: Does @Bernard 's hint help?: "Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage{lmodern}if unless you want a non-default font. – Bernard"

Comment: Ahh it works! Thank you so much and thanks @Bernard!

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{Titre}
\author{A. Uteur}
\maketitle

\today
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you get a warning on the console telling you

```
Package frenchb.ldf Warning: OT1 encoding should not be used for French.
(frenchb.ldf)                Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} to the preamble
(frenchb.ldf)                of your document; reported on input line 4.
```

which tells you how to, at least, avoid the warning. It not only avoids the warning, but makes TeX hyphenate properly words with accented letters.