# can't add 'ă' symbol in LATEX

Tags: pdftex

I have a question regarding writing a PDF in LATEX. I need to use diacritcs and I found out how to use some of them, but I can't add the 'ă' symbol. How can I do that?

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex).

Comment: If your keyboard has direct access to `ă`,  use `utf8` input encoding , `T1`font encoding, load  the `Latin Modern` font and just type it.

Answer (score 7):

You have two choices:

The first one is to include utf-8 encoding in the preamble. Then, you can write many special characters from your keyboard and they will be interpreted:

> \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
>
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> ă
>
> \end{document}

On the other hand, you can just use \u{a} without including the utf-8 package in the preamble. If you edit your documents in Kile, there is a list of special characters that fits most western languages, in case you do not known the code.

> \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \u{a}
>
> \end{document}

You may also want to check this page:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters

Comment: One way or the other, one should load also `fontenc` in order to make the pdf file searchable.