# Is there a 3 character "tie" accent?

Tags: accents

I've come across what appears to be a tie accent over three characters in the (transliterated) name of the author of a book. Specifically, over the "liu" in this book by [Bogoliubov](http://utah-primoprod.hosted.exlibrisgroup.com/primo_library/libweb/action/dlDisplay.do?vid=UTAH&search_scope=EVERYTHING&docId=UUU_ALMA21252811560002001&fn=permalink). Is there any way to replicate that in LaTeX?

Here's an image of the typeset name as it appears in both Firefox and Safari.[image: image of the typeset name]

The closest I can find (in 3 references: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/how-to-type-special-accented-letters-in-latex#8859), [2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters), and [3](http://www.thefullwiki.org/LaTeX/Accents)) is the "tie" accent, `\t`, but I can only get that to cover two letters.

Comment: Can you add a picture of a tie accent example?

Comment: Are you sure this is a 3 letter accent in the name of Bogoliubov really? The given link does show bad kerning rather than a 3 letter accent...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, I'm not. If it's bad kerning, does that mean it's over the "iu"?

Comment: @SeanLake: I know some Russian and how it is transcribed to German,  I am unsure about transcription of Cyrillic letters/names into English, but I would say, that the accent belongs to `iu` only

Comment: The name is Николай Николаевич Боголюбов in Cyrillic letters, so  ю is either transliterated into `u`, `iu` or i͡u  according to the [Transliteration Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Russian), in ALA-LC style

Comment: @Christian Why do you know Russian? :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I was bored as pupil, so I tried to learn a little bit of Russian ...

Comment: although this *could be* bad kerning, i think it is a situation where there is not a narrow enough glyph for the tie.  in traditional transliteration of russian, the first letter of a tied pair is always "i" and the second, another vowel, so the needed glyph should be narrower.