# Latex package for French words

Tags: errors

One of our references is from a French writer.
When loading a Latex file, because this reference is in the file, system's journals prints with a lot of errors.
What is a package in LaTeX for French words?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post  a minimal, yet complete, source code showing the problem?

Comment: Are you looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8857 ?